# Unable to add enable the scayt in toolbar in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

my `config.js` is as follow

```
    CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here.
    // For complete reference see:
    // http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config
    config.height='10em';
    // The toolbar groups arrangement, optimized for a single toolbar row.
    config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'document',    groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
        { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
        { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
        { name: 'forms' },
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ] },
        /*{ name: 'links' },*/
        { name: 'insert' },
        { name: 'styles' },
        { name: 'colors' },
        { name: 'tools' },
        { name: 'others' }
        /*{ name: 'about' }*/
    ];
    config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
    // The default plugins included in the basic setup define some buttons that
    // are not needed in a basic editor. They are removed here.
    config.removeButtons = 'Cut,Copy,Paste,Undo,Redo,Anchor,Underline,Strike,Subscript,Superscript';

    // Dialog windows are also simplified.
    config.removeDialogTabs = 'link:advanced';
    config.extraPlugins = 'scayt';
};
```

by adding `config.extraPlugins = 'scayt';` my `Ckeditor` is getting disabled I put scayt folder in plugins folder of CKEditor. Please help if you know what wrong I did. I want to add spell checker in CKeditor.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggeling with this too.
The solution for me was that the toolbar option had to start with a Capital "S"
so I had to use 'Scayt' instead of 'scayt'

```
CKEDITOR.config.toolbar_MA = [
    ['Scayt', '-', 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo', 'Source'],
];
CKEDITOR.config.disableNativeSpellChecker = false;
CKEDITOR.config.defaultLanguage = 'fr';
CKEDITOR.config.language = 'fr';

// Turn on SCAYT automatically
CKEDITOR.config.scayt_autoStartup = true;
CKEDITOR.config.scayt_sLang = 'fr_FR';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
config.scayt_autoStartup = true;
```

I didn't define:

```
config.extraPlugins = 'scayt';
```

And it was working

**EDIT**

You can also try initiating in javascript like here: http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/usz40fb5/

```
var editor;

function createEditor( lang ) {
    editor && editor.destroy();

    editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
        plugins: 'wysiwygarea,sourcearea,basicstyles,toolbar,scayt',
        // Turn on SCAYT automatically
        scayt_autoStartup: true,
        language: lang,
    } );
}

createEditor( 'en' );
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comment:

This one must work. Using version 4.4.3. The example I give is using CDN for ckeditor. If you want to replace to local js feel free to include your own script or download that script and load in from local library.

```
<!-- CKeditor 4.4.3  -->
<script src="http://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.4.3/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
<textarea  id="editor"> worng spelling</textarea>

<script>
// Shorthand for $( document ).ready()
$(function() {
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
            scayt_autoStartup: true
    });
});
</script>
```

See working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/KS3p4/8/

Comment: thank you for answer but by adding above code CKEDITOR is not getting disable but Spell check in not working.....

Comment: when i add this config.extraPlugins = 'scayt'; in config.js CKEDITOR is getting disable

Comment: @MonuMittal Any luck with this approach?

Comment: having error by adding above code     TypeError: CKEDITOR.instances.chiefComplaint is undefined
 

CKEDITOR.instances['chiefComplaint'].setData(data.chiefComplaint);